SpringBoot 2.x to 3.x Migration gives javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be converted to jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage
We are doing Spring 2.7.15 to 3.2.1 Migration.
As part of the code, we have
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

import jakarta.mail.MessagingException;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MyEmailService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailerService.class);

    @Autowired
    JavaMailSender mailSender;

    //As part of the call in a method we are calling
    public void sendMyEmail() {
       //This below line throws error
       MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    } 
}

We are getting error saying:

java: incompatible types: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be converted to jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage


Please share the whole class including imports as well as your pom.

Remove any javax.mail or single mail dependency you have and only use the spring-boot-starter-mail which includes all proper and compatible dependencies.

you want migration version 3.x.x

How about trying it JavaMailSender?
//in gradle..

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'

//in code..

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender; 
    
    public void sendMail() {

        try {
            MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, "utf-8");
            messageHelper.setTo("want send to email address");
            messageHelper.setSubject("your subjecT");
            messageHelper.setText("your content", true);
            javaMailSender.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new NotSendEmailException();
        }
    }


I am migrating from SpringBoot 2.7.15 to SpringBoot 3.2.1 .   I am using almost exact code and it's still failing with java: incompatible types: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be converted to jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage

After In version 3.x.x, use jakarata package
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage; to this

Maybe you are using an old version of the Jakarta Mail library? You should be using at least version 2.x, as stated by Spring documentation:

The following JAR needs to be on the classpath of your application in order to use the Spring Framework’s email support:
The Jakarta Mail library
This library is freely available on the web — for example, in Maven Central as com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail. Please make sure to use the latest 2.x version (which uses the jakarta.mail package namespace) rather than Jakarta Mail 1.6.x (which uses the javax.mail package namespace).


Thanks this suggestion almost worked.
It compiled successfully
However when I run the Application, I am now getting the following error:
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender]: Factory method 'mailSender' threw exception with message: Provider for jakarta.activation.spi.MimeTypeRegistryProvider cannot be found
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787)

When I run it, here is the code that is being called, where it's failing:
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
@Bean
public JavaMailSender mailSender(Environment env) {
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
mailSender.setHost(env.getProperty("spring.mail.host"));
mailSender.setPort(25);
mailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
return mailSender;
}

For me, the error was because I had set spring-framework.version=5.3.37 in gradle.properties. It finally worked when I deleted it.

Please use the javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage instead of the jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage.
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

@Autowired
JavaMailSender mailSender;


public void sendMyEmail() {
   MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
   ....................................
} 


Why would he do this? He is upgrading to Spring Boot 3.

Using javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage giving above error  javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be converted to jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage
So I included these in pom.xml  --> com.sun.mail jakarta.mail 2.0.1
changed javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage to jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage
This compiled successfully, however when I run the Application, I am getting following error:
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender]: Factory method 'mailSender' threw exception with message: Provider for jakarta.activation.spi.MimeTypeRegistryProvider cannot be found
